# Is there an easy way to add a last modified timestamp while using ORMLite and Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I want to add a field indicating the last modified or last accessed time for my objects. Is there an easy, auto refreshed method for doing so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure about how to use SQLite to support a last-modified timestamp.  However, one of the features of [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) is a version field.  You can mark a `Date` field with `version = true` and ever time it is updated it will update the `Date` to the latest value.  See the documentation for more information:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/version-field

So you would add something like the following to your class:

```
@DatabaseField(version = true)
Date modificationDate;
```

I've verified this works well both for the creation and modification dates.  Also, this means that when you do any upgrades, it will add something like the following to the end of the update statement automagically:

```
UPDATE yourclass SET ... >>> WHERE modificationDate = existing-date; <<<
```

See the docs for more information.  Oh, and if you'd like to store it as a long, instead you could do something like:

```
@DatabaseField(version = true, dataType = DataType.DATE_LONG)
Date modificationDate;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a trigger that updates your modificatoinDate each time an insert and update occurs in sqlite.

example:

```
db.execSQL("create trigger updateModDate " +
    "after insert on MY_TABLE for each row begin " +
    "update MY_TABLE set modificationDate = date('now') where id = NEW.id " +
    "end;");

db.execSQL("create trigger updateModDate " +
    "after update on MY_TABLE for each row begin " +
    "update MY_TABLE set modificationDate = date('now') where id = NEW.id " +
    "end;");
```

I believe triggers are available in the sqlite database used by Android.  I have not verified that these updates work, but this may be a transparent solution.

Im not sure about last access time.  I'd hate to see the performance of having to do an update every time a select is performed.

Comment: That's it!  "where id = NEW.id"